# STM Studio C++ array content visibility

Tags: stm32, stm32f4-discovery

I have been writing software for the MCU STM32F417. I have been using the STM Studio for debugging purposes. Unfortunately I have found that I am not able to observe content of an byte array. I am able to import only the first element of the array in the Import variables dialog. I can do a workaround based on definition of separate variable for each array element. This method is not suitable for my case because my array consists of 512 bytes.

Does anybody know whether some way exists how to import whole array into the STM Studio? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I mean the window "Import variables from executable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tickbox, expand table elements. (slow)

[image]

Then select all the ones you want and import.
*(ctrl + click for individuals, or shift + click for a range)*

Note that this tool is deceptive. It does not have a constant time base. It depends on the bus, and will add bus latency in the chip.
More variables means slower sample rate.

Aliasing is very likely.